# Notation for space of eventually-zero sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

An *eventually-zero sequence* is a real-valued sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ for which  there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n=0$ for each $n\geq N$. The space of eventually-zero sequences equipped with the sup-norm is usually denoted by $c_{00}$. I am working with the same underlying set of sequences, but in my case it is equipped with the $\ell^1$-norm. Is there any established notation for this space of sequences?

Comment: The standard notation is  $(\ell^{0},\|.\|_1)$ (or $(\ell_{0},\|.\|_1)$.

Comment: Thanks @KaviRamaMurthy. If I want to be brief, does it create any confusion if I simply write $\ell^0$?

Comment: If the norm is understood then you can write $\ell^{0}$.

Comment: Thanks again @KaviRamaMurthy, you've been a huge help. One more question, could you point me to an example where this notation is used? (It could be a book, a paper or a website--I've hunted high and low!)